# Is window.navigator.userAgent reliable

Tags: android, html, iphone, mobile

Is this a reliable means of device detection, ie iPad, iPhone, Android, etc.. ?

Or is there a sensible alternative ?

Is there a definitive list of device names ?

Many thanks..

Comment: Use feature detection, not browser detection. Why do you need to detect the browser in the first place?

Comment: A definitive list would always be changing with the appearance of new devices on the market, so answer is no to that one.